# PHP нажатие кнопки

Tags: php

Как обработать нажатие кнопки и выполнить то или иное действие, кнопка добавить комментарий

код страницы

```
   id="send">Отчет</button></th>
                </table>
        <div id = "welcome">sas</div>
        <script>
    
       //после загрузки DOM-дерева страницы
       document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
        //получить кнопку
        let send = document.getElementById('send');
        
        //подписаться на событие click по кнопке и назначить обработчик, который будет выполнять действия, указанные в безымянной функции
        send.addEventListener("click", function(){
          //1. Сбор данных, необходимых для выполнения запроса на сервере
          let date_from = document.getElementById('date_from').value;
          let date_to = document.getElementById('date_to').value;
          //Подготовка данных для отправки на сервер
          //т.е. кодирование с помощью метода encodeURIComponent
          date_from = 'date_from=' + encodeURIComponent(date_from)+ '&date_to=' + encodeURIComponent(date_to);
    
          // 2. Создание переменной request
          let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          // 3. Настройка запроса
          request.open('POST','xz.php',true);
          // 4. Подписка на событие onreadystatechange и обработка его с помощью анонимной функции
          request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            //если запрос пришёл и статус запроса 200 (OK)
            if ((request.readyState==4) && (request.status==200)) {
              // например, выведем объект XHR в консоль браузера
              console.log(request);
              // и ответ (текст), пришедший с сервера в окне alert
              console.log(request.responseText);
              // получить элемент c id = welcome
              let welcome = document.getElementById('welcome');
              // заменить содержимое элемента ответом, пришедшим с сервера
              welcome.innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
          });
          // Устанавливаем заголовок Content-Type(обязательно для метода POST). Он предназначен для указания кодировки, с помощью которой зашифрован запрос. Это необходимо для того, чтобы сервер знал как его раскодировать.
          request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
          // 5. Отправка запроса на сервер. В качестве параметра указываем данные, которые необходимо передать (необходимо для POST)
          request.send(date_from);
        });
      });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

код обработчика

```
   <?php

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
      if (strpos($key, 'Data') !== false){ 
        echo '<tr>
              <td></td> <td></td> 
              <td>'.str_replace("smd/", "",$value["id"]).'</td>
              <td>'.$value["all_events"].'</td>
              <td>'.$value["successfully"].'</td>
              <td>'.round((int)$value["successfully"]/(int)$value["all_events"]*100,2).'</td>
              <td>'.$value["repeated"].'</td> <td>'.round((int)$value["repeated"]/(int)$value["all_events"]*100,2).'</td>
              <td>'.((int)$value["successfully"]+(int)$value["repeated"]).'</td>
              <td>'.round(((int)$value["successfully"]+(int)$value["repeated"])/(int)$value["all_events"]*100,2).'</td>
              <td>'.((int)$value["all_events"]-(int)$value["successfully"]+(int)$value["repeated"]).'</td>
              <td>'.round(((int)$value["successfully"]+(int)$value["repeated"])/(int)$value["all_events"]*100,2).'</td> 
              <td>asdasdads<br><input type="button" name="'.str_replace("smd/", "",$value["id"]).'" id="comment" value="Добавить коментарий"></td>
             </tr>';
```

Конечная задача в следующем, по нажатию кнопки создается таблица на сервере и возвращается в клиентскую часть, в таблице в последних столбцах расположены кнопки, как написать обработчик этих кнопок

Comment: уточните, в чем конкретно проблема и желательно создайте **короткий** пример, который будет иллюстрировать проблему, зачем же весь сайт...

Comment: исправил немного

Comment: Всмысле как ? .`$('.class_button').click` или любое другое нужное событие